# Refer to REST API Reference in Team Foundation Server, how to bulk create bugs

Tags: javascript, tfs

Refer to [new APIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1) and [REST APIs for TFS 2015 and 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/wit/work-items?view=tfs-2018) it look like  I only can create a single bug, how to bulk create bugs in JavaScript?

Comment: Write the logic to create a single bug, then loop over that logic

Comment: @Daniel Mann  All right.I'll probably create thousands of bugs, and loops will make the browser responsive for a long time, so I expect batch operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Work item batch api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/WorkItemBatchUpdate?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

For example:

```
http://[collection url]/_apis/wit/$batch?api-version=1.0
```

Body:

```
[
  {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "uri": "/0511ScrumTFVC/_apis/wit/workItems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=1.0",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
    },
    "body": [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "apip1"
      },
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/id",
        "value": "-1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "uri": "/0511ScrumTFVC/_apis/wit/workItems/$Task?api-version=1.0",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
    },
    "body": [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "apip2"
      },
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/id",
        "value": "-2"
      }

    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Good!But the document does not write the maximum concurrency, perhaps it has an upper limit.

Comment: I tested and found that the maximum concurrent was 200.The error message returned is {"Message": "VS401397: Bulk update of 1000 work items exceed batch limit of 200"}

Comment: @soulxy So you can run the API in 5 threads if you want to create 1000 work items...